# Regenerating validation keys with ethereum staking

Tags: staking, keystore, keymanagement, validation

I am not in this situation but I want to understand what happens if:

- I have generated Ethereum validation keys.
- I have transferred this validations keys to a server (validation node), without keeping them.
- I have sent 32 Ether to Ethereum deposit contract.

Now, let's imagine I trash the server.

Is there a way to setup a new server and to regenerate validation keys ?

I think everything is lost because the public key involved with the 32 Ether deposit is linked to the validation key.

Is it possible to revoke a validation key and to re-generate a new one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you lose access to your keys, that 32 ETH is pretty much gone forever. There are some theoretical ways you could get the ETH back, but it's very unlikely. All cases have to do with restoring the private key.

- If you have a shell output that records the output of commands, and a command to generate the keys print your private keys out (this shouldn't have happened though)
- You are able to reset your computer to the exact same state down to the hardware level it was when it generated the keys in the first place, so when you create new keys it'll generate the same ones.

But yes, all in all, your keys are gone.

EDIT: If you give your keys to someone else, you cannot "revoke" access to them. That would be like telling someone a secret and then asking them to forget it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what happens in this scenario: I have kept my validation keys but i have send them to a friend which manages the validation node for me. If i have kept a copy of my keys, can i revoke them and re-generate new keys ?

Comment: You cannot "revoke" private key access. You'd have to move all your money to a new address with new keys. Whoever holds the keys has the power to do whatever they want with the crypto. It's like telling your friend a secret and then asking them to forget the secret.

Comment: Ok thanks. So you mean it is possible to change the withdrawal address if i keep my private access key ? but there is a delay for withdrawal...

Comment: No. You'd have to withdraw to the same address, move the funds to a new address with a new key, and deposit into the new address.

Comment: But we have to wait (exit queue) ? There is no way to speed up this process ? Thanks

Comment: Yes - but this sounds like it's a different question. If you have a new question, please ask the new question in the forum. You can check the validator enter and exit queues here: https://www.validatorqueue.com/

Comment: Thanks in fact I was expecting a way to "revoke" keys instantly but you have answered: it is not possible